# How to reference a variable in another class in java?

Tags: java

I am personally not on my PC right now so I cannot share my code, but I can try to rewrite a simple portion of it.

```
public class whatever()
{
    public int test;

    public String one = "placeholder" //to be filled later
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

and in another class,

```
public class test1()
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test = 1;
    }
}
```

In the class `test1`, I am getting an error saying test is undefined.

Comment: Java developers get confused if you don't follow the convention of starting classnames with a capital: `public class Whatever`. Your IDE probably gave you a warning about this.

Comment: Yes - thanks for the edit. I for some reason already has a test class non-capitalised on my IDE :-|

Answer (score 0):

You can't share variables like that - one class would not know the variables in the way you presented them.

One way to move variables around, you can first declare it in your main class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "test";
}
```

Then write a class that has a method which accepts a parameter to match your variable.

```
public class OtherClass {

    public void methodTest(String s) {
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

On the original class, you need to instantiate the new class

```
OtherClass oc = new OtherClass();
```

And then can call the method and pass in the desired parameter

```
oc.methodTest(s);
```

Main class now looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "test";
        otherClass oc = new OtherClass();
        oc.methodTest(s);
    }
```

And other class looks like (with a simple print statement):

```
public class OtherClass {

    public void methodTest(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

And this will print the value of `s`

I recommend taking some online tutorial for beginners, such as [this](http://courses.caveofprogramming.com/p/java-for-complete-beginners) or [this](http://www.java-made-easy.com/).

Comment: Thank you! My dev friends spent like an hour trying to figure this out, but now I can one-up them!

Comment: @GGSammy No problem. Feel free to accept and/or upvote if you are happy with the answer so that it may help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by importing the other class. This is my first class:

```
import package1.SecondClass;

public class FirstClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = SecondClass.varToRef;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

which prints out 8. My second class:

```
package package1;

public class SecondClass {
    public static int varToRef = 8;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
 }
```

I could only reference the variable when it was outside of the main method, made and referenced basically like a public static field of SecondClass.

Comment: Your second package doesnt make sense, wheres the class name? And its not necessary to import it because its in the same package...

Comment: @MCMastery FirstClass was in a default package, so I had to import SecondClass because they weren't in the same package. The classes are called FirstClass and SecondClass.